# MEDIA_ROOT vs MEDIA_URL (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, media-url

I read the documentation about [**MEDIA_ROOT**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#media-root) and [**MEDIA_URL**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#media-url) then I could understand them a little bit but not much.

**MEDIA_ROOT**:

- Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold [**user-uploaded files**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/).

**MEDIA_URL**:

- URL that handles the media served from [**MEDIA_ROOT**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#media-root), used for [**managing stored files**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/). It must end in a slash if set to a non-empty value. You will need to [**configure these files to be served**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-uploaded-files-in-development) in both development and production environments.

I frequently see them as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

So, what are **"MEDIA_ROOT"** and **"MEDIA_URL"** exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, I explain about **"MEDIA_ROOT"** then **"MEDIA_URL"**.

### <MEDIA_ROOT>

**"MEDIA_ROOT"** sets **the absolute path to the directory where uploaded files are stored** and **setting "MEDIA_ROOT" never ever influence to media file URL**.

For example, we have a django project:

[image]

Then, we set **"os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')" which is "C:\Users\kai\django-project\media" in Windows in my case** to **"MEDIA_ROOT"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # Here
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And set the code below to **"urls.py"**:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And set **the model "Image"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

And set the code below to **"admin.py"**:

```py
# "myapp/admin.py"

from .models import Image

admin.site.register(Image)
```

Then, upload **the file "orange.jpg"**:

[image]

Then, **"media" folder** is created at the same level as **"db.sqlite3"** and **"manage.py"** which is **just under the django project root directory** and **the uploaded file "orange.jpg"** is stored in **"media" folder** as shown below:

[image]

Then, upload more files:

[image]

In addition, we can display **the file "orange.jpg"** by clicking on **"orange.jpg"** on **"Change image" page of the file** as shown below:

[image]

Then, **the file "orange.jpg"** is displayed as shown below:

[image]

Be careful, if you remove the code below from **"urls.py"**:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then, **the file "orange.jpg"** is not displayed. Instead, there is an error as shown below:

[image]

Next, you can store uploaded files under **more subdirectories** and I explain 2 ways to do that and the first way is recommended because it is flexible and the second way is not recommended because it is not flexible at all.

The first way to store uploaded files under **more subdirectories** is
first, set **"os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')"** to **"MEDIA_ROOT"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # Here
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And, add **"upload_to='images/fruits'"** to **"models.ImageField()"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models  

class Image(models.Model):    # Here
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/fruits')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

Then, uploaded files are stored in **"C:\Users\kai\django-project\media\images\fruits" in Windows in my case** as shown below:

[image]

The second way to store uploaded files under **more subdirectories** is first, set **'media/images/fruits'** to **the second argument of "os.path.join()"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"
                                    # Here
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/images/fruits')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And set **no arguments** to **"models.ImageField()"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models  

class Image(models.Model): 
    image = models.ImageField() # Here

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

Then, uploaded files are stored in **"C:\Users\kai\django-project\media\images\fruits" in Windows in my case** as shown below but as I said before, the first way is recommended because it is flexible while the second way is not flexible at all:

[image]

In addition, if we don't set **"MEDIA_ROOT"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # Here
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Or set **an empty string** to **the second argument of "os.path.join()"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"
                                  
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '') # Here
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Or don't set **the second argument of "os.path.join()"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR) # Here
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And set **no arguments** to **"models.ImageField()"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models  

class Image(models.Model): 
    image = models.ImageField() # Here

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

Then, uploaded files are stored at the same level as **"db.sqlite3"** and **"manage.py"** which is **just under the django project root directory** as shown below:

[image]

In addition, after uploading files if we change **"MEDIA_ROOT"**, we cannot display uploaded files while we can still display uploaded files even if we change **"models.ImageField()"**.

For example, we set **"os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')"**  to **"MEDIA_ROOT"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # Here
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And, set **"upload_to='images/fruits'"** to **"models.ImageField()"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models  

class Image(models.Model):    # Here
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/fruits')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

Then, upload **the file "orange.jpg"**:

[image]

Then, click on **"images/fruits/orange.jpg"** on **"Change image" page of the file** as shown below:

[image]

Then, **the file "orange.jpg"** is displayed as shown below:

[image]

Now, we change **"MEDIA_ROOT"** from **"os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')"** to **"os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'hello/world')"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'hello/world') # Here
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Then again, click on **"images/fruits/orange.jpg"** on **"Change image" page of the file** as shown below:

[image]

Then, **the file "orange.jpg"** is not displayed. Instead, there is an error as shown below:

[image]

Then, as I said before, even if we change **"models.ImageField()"** after uploading files, we can still display uploaded files. So now, we change back **"MEDIA_ROOT"** from **"os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'hello/world')"** to **"os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # Here
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And, change **"models.ImageField(upload_to='images/fruits')"** to **"models.ImageField(upload_to='hello/world')"**:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models  

class Image(models.Model):    # Here
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='hello/world')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

Then again, click on **"images/fruits/orange.jpg"** on **"Change image" page of the file** as shown below:

[image]

Then, **the file "orange.jpg"** is displayed as shown below:

[image]

### <MEDIA_URL>

Next, I explain about **"MEDIA_URL"**.

**"MEDIA_URL"** sets **the directory(middle) part of media file URL** between **the host part and the file part of media file URL** as shown below and **setting "MEDIA_URL" never ever influence to the absolute path to the directory where uploaded files are stored**:

```
             Host        Directory      File
               |             |           |
        <-------------> <----------> <-------->      
https://www.example.com/media/images/orange.jpg
```

For example, we set **'/media/'** to **"MEDIA_URL"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' # Here
```

And set **no arguments** to **"models.ImageField()"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models  

class Image(models.Model): 
    image = models.ImageField() # Here

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

Then, upload **the file "orange.jpg"**:

[image]

Then, go to **"Change image" page of the file** then click on **"orange.jpg"**:

[image]

Then, **the URL of the file** is displayed as shown below:

[image]

As you can see, **the directory part "media"** is set between **the host part "localhost:8000"** and **the file part "orange.jpg"**

```
            Host    Directly   File
              |         |       |
       <------------> <---> <-------->      
http://localhost:8000/media/orange.jpg
```

And, this URL below is in this case of **"www.example.com"** with **"https"**:

```
             Host     Directly   File
               |          |       |
        <-------------> <---> <-------->      
https://www.example.com/media/orange.jpg
```

And, we can change **the directory part of URL** even after uploading files.

So, just change **"MEDIA_URL"** from **'/media/'** to **'/images/fruits/'** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/images/fruits/' # Here
```

Then, click on **"orange.jpg"** again:

[image]

Then, **the directory part "media"** is changed to **"image/fruits"** as shown below:

[image]

In addition, we can set **the directory part of URL with the combination of "MEDIA_URL" and "models.ImageField()"**. In this case, we can only change **the part of the directory part set by "MEDIA_URL"** after uploading files while we cannot change **the part of the directory part set by "models.ImageField()"** after uploading files:

For example, we set **'/media/'** to **"MEDIA_URL"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' # Here
```

And add **"upload_to='images/fruits'"** to **"models.ImageField()"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models  

class Image(models.Model):    # Here
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/fruits')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

Then, upload **the file "orange.jpg"**:

[image]

Then, go to **"Change image" page of the file** then click on **"images/fruits/orange.jpg"**:

[image]

Then, **the URL of the file** is displayed as shown below:

[image]

Then, the directory part is:

```
media/images/fruits
```

Now, we change **"MEDIA_URL"** from **'/media/'** to **'/hello/world/'**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/hello/world/' # Here
```

And, change **"models.ImageField(upload_to='images/fruits')"** to **"models.ImageField(upload_to='hey/earth')"**:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models  

class Image(models.Model):              # Here
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='hey/earth')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

Then, click on **"images/fruits/orange.jpg"** again:

[image]

Then, **the URL of the file** is displayed as shown below:

[image]

Then, we could change **the part of the directory part 'media' to 'hello/world' set by "MEDIA_URL"** after uploading **the file "orange.jpg"** while we couldn't change **the part of the directory part 'images/fruits' to 'hey/earth' set by "models.ImageField()"** after uploading **the file "orange.jpg"**:

```
hello/world/images/fruits
```

In addition, if we don't set **"MEDIA_URL"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
# MEDIA_URL = '/media/' # Here
```

Or set **an empty string** to **"MEDIA_URL"**  as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"
                                  
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '' # Here
```

Or set **one or more slashes** to **"MEDIA_URL"**  as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR)
MEDIA_URL = '/////' # Here
```

And set **no arguments** to **"models.ImageField()"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models  

class Image(models.Model): 
    image = models.ImageField() # Here

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

Then, **no directory part** is set  between **the host part "localhost:8000"** and **the file part "orange.jpg"** as shown below:

[image]

```
http://localhost:8000/orange.jpg
```